# The pager for this badge uses a page more

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

The pager on the [mortarboard badge](https://english.stackexchange.com/badges/25) page reports three pages, but just two pages are used. The users with that badge are 120, and 60 users are shown for each page; the third page is empty.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I see one user on page 3 - Edward Tanguay.

Comment: @Shog9 That is because the users with that badge are now 121. Previously, Edward Tanguay was the last user in the second page. I guess the problem is when the number of users with a badge is a multiple of 60 (the number of users shown in a page).

Comment: This would be a bug in calculating the number of pages.  The value of 1 is probably being added somewhere behind-the-scenes in some code, possibly related to a work-around for some other issue related to an index ID that starts at 0 instead of 1 (I've seen this sort of problem before in code for other things where this was the cause).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed a few months ago, just cleaning up the bug report. (: